# Subconsulta con STRING_SPLIT y PIVOT

Tags: sql-server

Hola buenos días comunidad, tengo un problema al momento de crear una subconsulta en SQL Server,
ésta es mi tabla original:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado que espero obtener es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no sé que este pasando en mi query que el resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi query es la siguiente:

```
SELECT [Date], campania, creativo, placement, SUM(impresiones) AS impresiones, 
       MAX(ISNULL([Columna1], '')) AS [Columna1],   MAX(ISNULL([Columna2], '')) AS [Columna2],   MAX(ISNULL([Columna3], '')) AS [Columna3], 
       MAX(ISNULL([Columna4], '')) AS [Columna4], MAX(ISNULL([Columna5], '')) AS [Columna5], MAX(ISNULL([Columna6], '')) AS [Columna6]
FROM(
    SELECT [Date], campania, creativo, placement,Orden,
            'Columna' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Date], Col_Value ORDER BY Orden) AS VARCHAR) AS ColPlacement,
            Col_Value, impresiones
    FROM (
        SELECT [Date], campania, creativo, placement,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Date] ORDER BY [Date]) AS Orden,
            Split.value AS Col_Value, impresiones
        FROM publicidad AS Pub
        CROSS APPLY string_split(placement, '-') AS Split
    ) X
) AS tblCampanias
    PIVOT (MAX(Col_Value) FOR ColPlacement IN ([Columna1], [Columna2], [Columna3], [Columna4], [Columna5], [Columna6])) AS pvtPlacement
GROUP BY [Date], campania, creativo, placement
ORDER BY [Date]
```

Alguien puede orientarme un poco para poder llegar al resultado deseado.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una manera de realizarlo.

Lo que generalmente hago es nombrar las columnas a las que aplicare PIVOT, utilizando ROW_NUMBER().

Solo hay que revisar si el PARTITION BY, efectivamente debe ser por fecha, eso depende si quieres agrupar campañas, o campañas por fecha.

```
SELECT [Date], campania, creativo, placement,  
        MAX(ISNULL([DatosPublicacion_1], '')) [DatosPublicacion_1],
        MAX(ISNULL([DatosPublicacion_2], '')) [DatosPublicacion_2],
        MAX(ISNULL([DatosPublicacion_3], '')) [DatosPublicacion_3],
        MAX(ISNULL([DatosPublicacion_4], '')) [DatosPublicacion_4],
        MAX(ISNULL([DatosPublicacion_5], '')) [DatosPublicacion_5],
        MAX(ISNULL([DatosPublicacion_6], '')) [DatosPublicacion_6],
        MAX(ISNULL([DatosPublicacion_7], '')) [DatosPublicacion_7],
        SUM(impresiones) AS impresiones
FROM(
   SELECT  
        [Date], campania, creativo, placement, Col_Value, impresiones,
        CONCAT('DatosPublicacion','_', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Date] ORDER BY [Date])) AS DatosPublicacion
    FROM
    (
        SELECT [Date], campania, creativo, placement,
                Split.value AS Col_Value, impresiones
        FROM publicidad AS Pub
        CROSS APPLY string_split(placement, '-') AS Split
    )T
) AS tblCampanias
    PIVOT (MAX(Col_Value) FOR DatosPublicacion IN([DatosPublicacion_1],[DatosPublicacion_2],[DatosPublicacion_3],[DatosPublicacion_4],[DatosPublicacion_5],[DatosPublicacion_6],[DatosPublicacion_7])) AS pvtPlacement
GROUP BY [Date], campania, creativo, placement
ORDER BY [Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero el escenario:

```
Create Table dbo.publicidad
             (
             campania    VarChar(Max)
           , creativo    VarChar(Max)
           , placement   VarChar(Max)
           , impresiones Decimal(5, 2)
           , fecha       Date
             );
Go

Insert into dbo.Publicidad(campania, creativo, placement, impresiones, Fecha)
values
( 'Bienestar Familiar'
 ,'XXBIEN_ESTAR-FAMILIAR-JPEG-700X200'
 ,'XXX_DIS_GEN_PUBLIC_-BIENESTAR&FAMILIAR-VRZ-SOCIALPH-TV-NA-NA'
 ,145.00
 ,'20210102'
),
( 'Estamos Contigo'
 ,'XXXBIEN_ESTAMOS-CONTIGO-GIF-300X100'
 ,'XXX_DIS_GEN_PUBLIC_-ESTAMOS&CONTIGO-CDMX-SOCIALPH-TV-NA-NA'
 ,500.00
 ,'20210115'
),
( 'Siempre Fuertes'
 ,'XXBIEN_SIEMPRE-FUERTES-JPEG-500X350'
 ,'XXX_DIS_GEN_PUBLIC_-SIEMPRE&FUERTES-CHI-SOCIALPH-TV-NA-NA'
 ,326.00
 ,'20210203'
);
GO
```

Uno de los problemas que tiene [string_Split](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), es que no puede garantizar el orden de devolución de los items. (Ver Observaciones de la documentación). Y lo mismo ocurre con [row_number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613055/is-order-by-and-row-number-deterministic) cuando el criterio de ordenación no es determinista. Si varios registros tienen la misma fecha, unas veces te puede devolver un registro como primer elemento y otras veces otro.

Lo primero es utilizar una función para hacer el split que nos provea de un orden. Para el ejemplo vamos a utilizar [delimitedSplit8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function), que funciona bastante bien. En el enlace, dispones de un artículo, que explica el como funciona.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
```

Con la función disponible, para hacer un split, tan solo tenemos que hacer un simple pivot

```
SELECT pvt.Fecha as [Date]
, pvt.campania
, pvt.creativo
, pvt.placement
, pvt.[1] as [Columna 1]
, pvt.[2] as [Columna 2]
, pvt.[3] as [Columna 3]
, pvt.[4] as [Columna 4]
, pvt.[5] as [Columna 5]
, pvt.[6] as [Columna 6]
, pvt.[7] as [Columna 7]

FROM (
SELECT * 
From dbo.Publicidad p cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(p.placement,'-')FN
) AS SOURCE
PIVOT (MAX(ITEM) FOR ITEMNUMBER IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]))PVT
```

[image: Resultado]